# Reducing Sparse CSR-Matrix Still Further

Tags: python, matrix, scipy, jupyter-notebook, sparse-matrix

When trying to calculate a sparse csr-adjacency-matrix for the `ogb-products` graph I encounter the problem that google colab is crashing because it still takes up too much RAM. There are roughly 12 million non-zero entries in that adjacency matrix. the original adjacency matrix would be of size 2500000x2500000.

The code snippet that causes this problem:

```
dataset = PygNodePropPredDataset(name='ogbn-products', transform=T.ToSparseTensor())
data = dataset[0]
features = data.x

row, col, edge_attr = data.adj_t.t().coo()
adj_values = [1]*len(row)
adj = csr_matrix((adj_values, (row,col)), shape=(data.x.shape[0],data.x.shape[0])) <------- this causes the crash
```

Is there any way to get a sparse matrix that does not crash google colab?

Comment: try using `adj_values=np.ones(len(row))`.  Also show full error traceback if possible.

Comment: @hpaulj I don't get an error message. The RAM usage bar in the upper right corner goes to its maximum and then colab just crashes. I also changed the code with your given improvement but it still crashes.

Comment: Back of the envelope calculations say a CSR matrix of that size (2.5m x 2.5m) with 12m non-zero entries should be around 200MB in memory. You should probably try to do a bit more debugging to find what exactly isn't matching up with that expectation.